# JSON Strigify returns only parent

Tags: jquery, json, object

I tried using JSON strigify but it returns me only:

```
{"name":"nipahVirus","children":{}}
```

It is because of my format data type converted wrongly? Or any places that I have done. Would be appreciated if someone can help me out.
I am working on a csv convert to JSON.

Here is my code.

```
    function findSpecies(name){
    var objspecies = {};
    Papa.parse("nipahdata.csv", {
        download: true,
        complete: function(results) {

            for(i = 0;i < results.data.length; i ++){
                var species = {};    
                if(name == results.data[i][0]){
                species["name"] = results.data[i][1];
                species["niv_status"] = results.data[i][2];
                objspecies[results.data[i][0]] = species; 
                }
            }

        }
    });    
    return objspecies;
}        

var nipahVirus_obj = {};
var genus = {};
Papa.parse("nipahdata.csv", {
    download: true,
    complete: function(results) {
        var currgenus = "";        
        for(i = 0;i < results.data.length; i ++){


            if(results.data[i][0] == "")
            continue; 

            if(currgenus != results.data[i][0]){
                var objgenus = {};
                currgenus = results.data[i][0];
                objgenus["name"] = results.data[i][0];
                objgenus["children"]=findSpecies(results.data[i][0]);
                genus[results.data[i][0]] = objgenus;
            }

        }

    }
});
        nipahVirus_obj["name"] = "nipahVirus";
        nipahVirus_obj["children"] = genus;    
        var nipahVirus_JSON = JSON.stringify(nipahVirus_obj);
        console.log(nipahVirus_JSON);
```

The csv is something like this which contains three columns:

```
Genus,Species Name,NiV status
Craseonycteris,Craseonycteris_thonglongyai,0
Emballonura,Emballonura_alecto,0
Emballonura,Emballonura_dianae,0
Emballonura,Emballonura_furax,0
Emballonura,Emballonura_raffrayana,0
Emballonura,Emballonura_serii,0
Emballonura,Emballonura_monticola,0
Emballonura,Emballonura_beccarii,0
Emballonura,Emballonura_semicaudata,0
Mosia,Mosia_nigrescens,0
Saccolaimus,Saccolaimus_flaviventris,0
Saccolaimus,Saccolaimus_saccolaimus,0
```

Comment: What does the format of the csv, which you try to parse, look like?

Comment: @Geshode I have added the csv format

Answer (score 0):

There is a async progress in the function findSpecies,and objspecies which you return actually is {} you defined,and not the data which return in complete.you can define a callback function,and call it in complete.the code maybe like this,as there are two post,i can't debug it,you should run it in your environment by yourself,and check it.

```js
function findSpecies(name){
    var objspecies = {};
    Papa.parse("nipahdata.csv", {
        download: true,
        complete: function(results) {

            for(i = 0;i < results.data.length; i ++){
                var species = {};    
                if(name == results.data[i][0]){
                species["name"] = results.data[i][1];
                species["niv_status"] = results.data[i][2];
                objspecies[results.data[i][0]] = species; 
                }
            }
            callback(objspecies)
        }
    });    
}        
var objgenus = {};
var nipahVirus_obj = {};
var genus = {};
Papa.parse("nipahdata.csv", {
    download: true,
    complete: function(results) {
        var currgenus = "";        
        for(i = 0;i < results.data.length; i ++){


            if(results.data[i][0] == "")
            continue; 

            if(currgenus != results.data[i][0]){
                
                currgenus = results.data[i][0];
                objgenus["name"] = results.data[i][0];
                findSpecies(results.data[i][0]);
            }

        }

    }
});

      function callback(data){
        objgenus["children"]=data
        genus[results.data[i][0]] = objgenus;
        nipahVirus_obj["name"] = "nipahVirus";
        nipahVirus_obj["children"] = genus;    
        var nipahVirus_JSON = JSON.stringify(nipahVirus_obj);
        console.log(nipahVirus_JSON);
       }
```